# Post type no single page

Tags: posts, functions, single, post-type

I have created a post type and I am trying to create a single page for that post type, I am creating a php file called `single-job.php` and it is using the `index.php` as a template. Below is my function for creating the post type:

```
add_action( 'init', 'register_cpt_job' );
function register_cpt_job() {

    $labels = array( 
        'name' => _x( 'Job posts', 'job' ),
        'singular_name' => _x( 'Job post', 'job' ),
        'add_new' => _x( 'Add New', 'job' ),
        'add_new_item' => _x( 'Add New Job post', 'job' ),
        'edit_item' => _x( 'Edit Job post', 'job' ),
        'new_item' => _x( 'New Job post', 'job' ),
        'view_item' => _x( 'View Job post', 'job' ),
        'search_items' => _x( 'Search Job posts', 'job' ),
        'not_found' => _x( 'No job posts found', 'job' ),
        'not_found_in_trash' => _x( 'No job posts found in Trash', 'job' ),
        'parent_item_colon' => _x( 'Parent Job post:', 'job' ),
        'menu_name' => _x( 'Job posts', 'job' ),
    );

    $args = array( 
        'labels' => $labels,
        'hierarchical' => true,

        'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor' ),
        'taxonomies' => array( 'category' ),
        'public' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_in_menu' => true,


        'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'can_export' => true,
        'rewrite' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post'
    );

    register_post_type( 'job', $args );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, before you start, just reflush your permalinks. It is sometimes strange why the [Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy) fails. You code checks out, and should in theory work. Everything checks out, and to make sure, I tested it on my side.

You can use this work around to "force" wordpress to use a template. Here we would use [`template_include`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/template_include) filter hook.

```
<?php
function wpse_template_include( $original_template ) {
    if ( isset( $wp->query_vars['job'] ) && false == $wp->query_vars['job']  ) {
        return get_template_directory() . '/single-job.php';
    } else {
        return $original_template;
    }
}

add_filter( 'template_include', 'wpse_template_include' );
```

Comment: Hey I just tried this added it to the bottom of my functions.php and it doesnt work still!

Comment: Are you looking for a single page or an archive page

Comment: And are you using a child theme or parent theme

Comment: Single im using `<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>` to get the link for the post and it is just 404ing and im using a parent theme

Comment: Please add the code for your single-post.php Have you flushed your permalinks? A 404 usually is fixed in CPT's by just visiting the permalink page and clicking "Save Changes"

Comment: what!!!! Thats such an annoying thing! thank you for that!

Comment: Qiute annoying! I sometimes forget that too, lol. Great that your problem is solved :-)